# Chromecast as sender to Raspberry

Tags: chromecast

I would just like to know, if it is possible to attach my Chromecast to a Raspberry? 
I want to achieve that my Smartphone can act as a monitor for the attached Raspberry.

So in short: can I revert the Chromecast functions? From receiving to sending video signals?

Comment: I think your going to struggle with that, I suggest looking into using VNC.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use your phone as a monitor for your Raspberry Pi, then just use [TightVNC](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/) on the pi and a VNC client on your phone.